# How to test Facebook Ads conversion for Mobile Apps?

Tags: facebook, ads, fbsdk

I have implemented the Facebook SDK and App Events in the mobile app. I have already tested it using Facebook Events Manager. Events are properly reported with no errors.

I want to test it with ads. Is there a way to do it using Ads Preview? We tried it but Ads Reporting is not showing any event against the ads.

Is there any way to test without running an ad campaign?

Answer (score 0):

You can test it using [whitehat account](https://www.facebook.com/whitehat/accounts/). Using it you can add campaigns, adsets and ads in "test" mode. App events work as well.